# How to retrieve cmake target names from vcpkg?

Tags: cmake, vcpkg, target-link-libraries

After installing a package, vcppkg very helpfully displays the relevant CMake targets...

> The package libwebp:x64-windows provides CMake targets:

```
find_package(WebP CONFIG REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE WebP::webp WebP::webpdemux WebP::libwebpmux WebP::webpdecoder)
```

But if you don't copy them then you may never see them again.  At least I can't find them.  Does anyone know how to retrieve this information for an installed package?

Comment: Run vcpkg install <package_name> again. It will show you. Of course it will not install it since it exists. So it is quite fast

Comment: @stardust It doesn't seem to provide the cmake target names anymore (in macOS with `vcpkg` as of commit `cd7f976`

Comment: nevermind, it's not providing them for a specific package (antlr4)

Answer (score 6):

If you installed `libwebp` via:

```
$ ./vcpkg install libwebp
```

Then simply running it a second time will show you the usage information:

```
$ ./vcpkg install libwebp
Computing installation plan...
The following packages are already installed:
    libwebp[core,nearlossless,simd]:x64-linux -> 1.1.0#3
Package libwebp:x64-linux is already installed

Total elapsed time: 12.88 us

The package libwebp:x64-linux provides CMake targets:

    find_package(WebP CONFIG REQUIRED)
    target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE WebP::webp WebP::webpdemux WebP::libwebpmux WebP::webpdecoder)
```

This works for all packages that show usage information in the first place.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71734004/how-to-know-the-name-of-a-library-installed-with-vcpkg?noredirect=1#comment126773490_71734004

Comment: It doesn't show all the targets though, for ex with opencv4, I have this: 
```The package opencv4 provides CMake targets:

    find_package(OpenCV CONFIG REQUIRED)
    # note: 59 targets were omitted.
    target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE opencv_ml opencv_dnn opencv_dpm opencv_hdf)```

However, I found the targets in vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\share\opencv\*cmake files.

Comment: This doesnt seem to work if you are using vcpkg in manifest mode:

(csp) C:\Users\csp>.\vcpkg\vcpkg.exe install gtest
error: In manifest mode, `vcpkg install` does not support individual package arguments.
To install additional packages, edit vcpkg.json and then run `vcpkg install` without any package arguments.
See https://learn.microsoft.com/vcpkg/users/manifests for more information.

Comment: @ByteMe95 - This answer was written before manifest mode was really a thing. If you write a new answer, I'll upvote it.